# Kaizala Web is crashing due to accessing an undefined variable

Tags: kaizala

We adopted Kaizala as a way for our employees to stay in touch with our customers. Kaizala itself is installed on a Tablet every employee has and they are mainly using the Web App of Kaizala for communication.
After roughly 1 month, today the web app of one employee consistently fails. Meaning after providing a location, the phone number and the code for coupling, the web app briefly shows the list of chats and groups and than turns white. This happens on all major browsers only for this user.

In the DevTools theres this output

```
webcommon.js?v=1.1.20.0713.173537:164 TypeError: Cannot read property 'convId' of undefined
    at Function.mapToProps (webapp.js?v=1.1.20.0713.173537:47)
    at r (webcommon.js?v=1.1.20.0713.173537:1)
    at Function.r.mapToProps (webcommon.js?v=1.1.20.0713.173537:1)
    at r (webcommon.js?v=1.1.20.0713.173537:1)
    at webcommon.js?v=1.1.20.0713.173537:1
    at Object.run (webcommon.js?v=1.1.20.0713.173537:1)
    at a.initSelector (webcommon.js?v=1.1.20.0713.173537:1)
    at new Connect(t) (webcommon.js?v=1.1.20.0713.173537:1)
    at constructClassInstance (webcommon.js?v=1.1.20.0713.173537:164)
    at beginWork (webcommon.js?v=1.1.20.0713.173537:164)
```

Which I traced to this location (pretty printed, in webapp.js), the error mentioned above happens on the 3rd row.

```js
    t.ConversationItemContainer = i.connect((function(e, t) {
        var n = e.conversationsState.allConversations[t.convId]
        , i = e.conversationsState.allConversationsMetadata[t.convId]
        , r = e.conversationsState.selectedConversation === n.convId
        , a = t.conversationItemIndex
        , l = t.conversationListSize
        , u = o.conversationsSelectors.getAccessPolicyResult(e, n.convId)
        , p = c.groupManagerSelectors.getTenantData(e, n.tenantId);
```

And in there, `t.convId` is `undefined` but other attributes are set.

Does someone has an idea what maybe is the source problem?

**[Update]**
Using break points in Chrome's DevTools I could see, that in line

```js
var n = e.conversationsState.allConversations[t.convId]
```

the value for `t.convId` was `undefined`, which led to line

```js
r = e.conversationsState.selectedConversation === n.convId
```

throwing the mentioned TypeError, to the fact, that `n` was `undefined`

Comment: please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by mere luck I think. In all groups that one employee (with the problems) was in, there also was at least one other employee in. Other employees didn't had those problems, so I guessed, that the problem of the crashing web app didn't come from groups but from one-on-one conversations.
Having the employee with the problems delete all the one-on-one conversations resulted in solving the problem. Now we can only guess that maybe in one of those conversations there was only one message which got deleted. And maybe with the deletion of that one message (being the only one in the conversation) the whole conversation was deleted but not completeley. That's at least what I can guess due to the fact that `t.convId` was undefined.